# How to set foreign key with an additional constraint

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have a mysql database with the following tables (InnoDB):

```
products
--id
--name 
--description
--parentid
```

and

```
categories2products
--id
--productid
```

I would like to have a foreign key for categories2products.productid to prodoucts.id where parentid=null how would I do this? (is it possible) I know how to set a foreign key just not sure how to do it with the parentid=null as well.

thanks

Comment: Your question is about the table category, is it a typo?

Comment: sorry yes it is, will update

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit unclear as to what parentid is. If it is a self relationship pointing to "products" table, just set it as nullable in mysql. The foreing key has no relation to this and you can set it normally.

If you mean you want the foreign-key only to be available when parentid is null, then that would be managed by the application using the database. The foreign-key contraint needs to be defined and the app will either populate it when there is no parent or leave it null whent there is a parent.

Hope that helped. If I understood it incorrectly, please edit the question to make it clearer.

Comment: Yes the foreign key values should only be available, when parentid is null. the parent id is linked to id on the same table (products). I wanted to ensure data integrity by setting the rule with in the database if at all posiblle. As my application already applies these rules. (I like to set things in the database to stop any errors in code changes for not respecting data integrity)

Answer (score 0):

A foreign key cannot accomplish the constraint you want; you can often implement more complex constraints (like the one you are trying) by using BEFORE triggers that "throw errors" when the constraint is not met.

However, this could easily grow beyond practicality. Using a BEFORE INSERT trigger on the referencing table to prevent improper data being inserted would be simple enough, as would a BEFORE UPDATE trigger to prevent inappropriate updates... but you'd have to resolve what happens if a referenced record is ever changed in manner that makes in ineligible for reference. *You'd also need to implement triggers on the referenced table if you wanted to emulate a foreign key's cascade features.*